# NRPE: Unable to read output

Tags: nagios

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


DEFAULT_WARN_SECONDS=60
DEFAULT_CRIT_SECONDS=120


while getopts  'hp:c:w:' option; do
    case $option in
        h) help=1;;
        p) path=$OPTARG;;
        c) crit=$OPTARG;;
        w) warn=$OPTARG;;
    esac
done

if [ -n "$help" ] || [ -z "$path" ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 -p [path (required)] -w [warning threshhold seconds] -c [critical threshhold seconds]" 1>&2
    exit 4
elif ! [ -e "$path" ]; then
    echo "fatal: invalid or unreadable file path provided: $path" 1>&2
    exit 3
fi

if [ -z "$warn" ]; then
    warn=$DEFAULT_WARN_SECONDS
fi
if [ -z "$crit" ]; then
    crit=$DEFAULT_CRIT_SECONDS
fi

seconds=$(($(date +'%s') - $(stat --format='%Y' $path)))

if [ $seconds -gt $crit ]; then
    echo "CRITICAL: $path was last modified $seconds seconds ago"
    exit 1
elif [ $seconds -gt $warn ]; then
    echo "WARNING: $path was last modified $seconds seconds ago"
    exit 2
else
    echo "OK: $path was last modified $seconds seconds ago"
    exit 0
fi
```

When I run the script in localhost it is working :

```
./check_last -p /root/Ratify/apache-tomcat-ratify/target/ratify.log -w 30 -c 40
**output:**
OK: /root/Ratify/apache-tomcat-ratify/target/ratify.log was last modified 24 seconds ago
```

When I run the script from remote server it is not working :

```
./check_nrpe -H 00.00.0.00 -c check_ratify
NRPE: Unable to read output
```

Please suggest solution.

Comment: Check the `nrpe.cfg` file in order to look for the command name `check_ratify`.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a permissions issue. If the `nrpe` or `nagios` user can't access the path you are trying to `stat`, you'll get that. And I see your example is trying to access a file under the `/root` directory, which is only readable by the superuser.

So, I guess you're running your local example as root, but the remote check is run as `nrpe` or `nagios`. If you really need to access that path, you have to configure permissions accordingly.